# linkedin underlying connection was closed

Tags: linkedin-api

Our app uses oauth2 with linkedin to post to our customer's LI profile.  The method to authorize a user works fine however the next section of code to get the access token results in an "Underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" exception.  The inner exception says "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream".

I've verified our application credentials are correct and this had been working up until today as far as we can tell.  The errors make it sound like an issue on LinkedIn's side, but I'm not 100% sure.  Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this?

Here's the code of the method that's failing.

```
var accessCodeUri =
string.Format(
    "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?format=json&grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}",
    authorizationCode,
    redirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
    linkedInApiKey,
    linkedInSecretKey);
string responseFromServer = string.Empty;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(accessCodeUri).AbsoluteUri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.Headers["UserAgent"] = "JB oAuth2";

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

string postData = string.Empty;
byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
dataStream.Write(postArray, 0, postArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
return responseFromServer;
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding the following to the top of the method seems to have fixed the problem.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Thx! That did it for me! Looks like LinkedIn changed their security protocol support without telling anyone :(

Comment: Actually, I think they did... I just missed it until today.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/phase-two-our-tls-10-11-deprecation-plan-miles-mulcare/

Comment: LOL that's over a year old! Nice of them to keep their devs informed in a timely manner...

Comment: Would be nice of them to have added a note on this in their authorization code flow documents.................anyways thanks all!